# Loading text from resource (.res) file gives strange characters

Tags: delphi, embedded-resource, delphi-10.3-rio

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8861635/loading-text-from-resource-res-file) question I want to know how to solve the problem of strange characters appearing, even having text file saved as Unicode.

[image]

```
function GetResourceAsPointer(ResName: PChar; ResType: PChar; out Size: LongWord): Pointer;
var
  InfoBlock: HRSRC;
  GlobalMemoryBlock: HGLOBAL;
begin
  Result := nil;
  InfoBlock := FindResource(hInstance, ResName, ResType);
  if InfoBlock = 0 then
    Exit;
  Size := SizeofResource(hInstance, InfoBlock);
  if Size = 0 then
    Exit;
  GlobalMemoryBlock := LoadResource(hInstance, InfoBlock);
  if GlobalMemoryBlock = 0 then
    Exit;
  Result := LockResource(GlobalMemoryBlock);
end;

function GetResourceAsString(ResName: pchar; ResType: pchar): string;
var
  ResData: PChar;
  ResSize: Longword;
begin
  ResData := GetResourceAsPointer(ResName, ResType, ResSize);
  SetString(Result, ResData, ResSize);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   ShowMessage(GetResourceAsString('TESTANDO', 'TXT'));
end;
```

Comment: How do you create the resource? Using an RC file or using resourcestring keyword? Are the strange characters extra characters or transformed characters? Showing what create the resource string could help.

Comment: Any particular reason why you are using a raw resource and not using `resourcestring`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using `SizeOfResource()` which returns the size in **bytes**.

```
Size := SizeofResource(hInstance, InfoBlock);
```

but you are using it as if it were number of **characters**

```
SetString(Result, ResData, ResSize);
```

Because `SizeOf(Char)` is 2, you are reading into the string what happens to be in the memory after the actual text.

Solution is obviously

```
SetString(Result, ResData, ResSize div SizeOf(Char));
```

Comment: Then what is solution? Something like: `SetString(Result, ResData, SizeOf(ResData) * 2);` ?

Comment: @Davison Divide by 2.